# Whole control the green led on RPI 3B+

Tags: gpio, led

I would like to learn gpio control on raspberry pi, and now I have a RPI 3B+

I found that the greed led is GPIO29
I think it will work to set the green led on or off by gpio, but at the same time, the green led also is control by SDcard.

So, it's not easy for me to observe the green led, is any method that I can untie the green led controlling by SDcard?

Comment: add `dtparam=act_led_trigger=none` in `config.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
dtparam=act_led_trigger=none
```

in `/boot/config.txt` and reboot